# Use host specific file if it exists instead of the one from role?

Tags: file, ansible

Is there a way to replace files that are copied, when such file exists on host similarly as you can do with variables (you can override variable on host, to use custom value if needed)?

Currently I'm doing like this:

```yaml
- name: Check if path exists
  set_fact:
    file_nginx_logo: "files/{{ inventory_hostname }}/maintenance_logo.png"

- name: Create Nginx Maintenance Image file (custom).
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "files/{{ inventory_hostname }}/maintenance_logo.png"
    dest: "{{ path_nginx_logo }}"
  when: file_nginx_logo is file

- name: Create Nginx Maintenance Image file (default).
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: maintenance_logo.png
    dest: "{{ path_nginx_logo }}"
  when: file_nginx_logo is not file
```

But this is quite ugly as I need 3 (or 2) tasks to copy one file.. Maybe there is a place in `inventory` path where if you put it, it would overwrite file defined on role?

I mean, something like:

```
files/my-host/my-file.txt
roles/my-role/files/my-file.txt
```

So if you call `my-file.txt` on `my-role` it would use the one from `my-host` if such file exists there?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a full blown example. Adapt to you needs.

Global test project stucture:

```
.
├── files
│   └── host2
│       └── maintenance_logo.txt
├── inventories
│   └── default
│       └── hosts.yml
├── roles
│   └── test
│       ├── files
│       │   └── maintenance_logo.txt
│       └── tasks
│           └── main.yml
└── test_playbook.yml
```

The test inventory in `inventories/default/hosts.yml` points to localhost in all cases:

```yaml
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
  hosts:
    host1:
    host2:
```

As you can see, the role holds the default logo where we will fallback whereas there is specific logo for `host2` in the `files` dir adjacent to the playbook. (I used txt source files for this example for convenience but this will work with any type of file)

In `roles/test/tasks/main.yml` we have a single task:

```yaml
- name: Copy maintenance logo to target
  vars:
    candidate_files:
      - "{{ inventory_hostname }}/maintenance_logo.txt"
      - maintenance_logo.txt
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}.png
  loop: "{{ q('ansible.builtin.first_found', candidate_files) }}"
```

The key here is using the [`ansible.builtin.first_found` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/first_found_lookup.html) which will exit on first found file (as its name obviously suggest...) and return its name.

This lookup obeys the [ansible search path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbook_pathing.html) so we can use the file name relative to any correctly placed `files` folder anywhere in playbook directory, roles, etc...

Note that I used `inventory_hostname` in the destination file names as I faked all my test hosts to local in my inventory. You obviously do not have to do that on your separate targets (i.e. use whatever target name you wish)

Now the `test_playbook.yml` to wrap it all up

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.import_role:
        name: test
```

Which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/default/ test_playbook.yml 

PLAY [all] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test : Copy maintenance logo to target] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host2] => (item=/tmp/test/files/host2/maintenance_logo.txt)
changed: [host1] => (item=/tmp/test/roles/test/files/maintenance_logo.txt)

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```